# MovieClip sticks to all frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have a MovieClip with 5 frames. On it are some other movieclips, quite a few of them. On every frame of the first MovieClip they are positoned differently and when I change the frame they change location. Everything works great until I change something within the actionscript.

If I try to color the child MovieClip or do anything with it and then change the frame, the MC stays on the same spot, it does not change location like it should (and does if I dont change it).

Why is this happening? Can I do something to fix it?
Thank you :)

Comment: May be you can show us some of your code to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position of the movieclips dynamically, using actionscript on each frame, instead of directly on the stage.

```
[movieclip].x = [Number];
[movieclip].y = [Number];
```

I'm pretty sure objects that have been referenced in actionscript tend to ignore the IDE positioning in later frames, so you need to dynamically move them. I've seen it happen to me heaps of times.